# Parse error checking array keys

Tags: php

I'm running into a strange parse error in PHP5 ...
When I remark line 529, everything works fine.
I don't see my misstake there?
I'm checking for the existance of array keys elsewhere too... and PHP never complained... Do you see, what's wrong?

```
/* 527 */ if (!isset($secuText))    { $secuText = array("","",""); }
/* 528 */ if (!is_array($secuText)) { $secuText = array("","",""); }
/* 529 */ if (!isset($secuText[0])) { $secuText[0] = ""; }
```

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '$secuText' (T_VARIABLE) in **/.../doc-delivery.php** on line **529**

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the code you've pasted

Comment: I've split the if block into multiple "if's" already to isolate the part that causes the problem. PHP definately complains about the part in line 529.

Comment: I often have problems with `||` in Eclipse when writing PHP code (doesn't happen with other languages) running on OS X Mavericks. It also reports me non existing syntax errors, and I have to erase the line and type it again...

Comment: Post the surrounding code also?

Comment: Believe it or not, but Martin's comment was the solution. I've retyped the line and it works. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

Try array_key_exists function:

```
   /* 527 */ if (!isset($secuText))    { $secuText = array("","",""); }
   /* 528 */ if (!is_array($secuText)) { $secuText = array("","",""); }
   /* 529 */ if (array_key_exists(0,$secuText) && !isset($secuText[0])) { $secuText[0] ="";
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives me the exact same error. Just tried it. Checked my recend changes in the above code as well, can't find any missing brackets. Even if I undo all those changes. The error makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: I did not see error in my local host in page or server error log by running this code and in here also there are no error : https://eval.in/86355